# Can not set the compiler flags for Fortran using Cmake

Tags: cmake, fortran, gfortran

I would like to use CMake to build fortran source codes. I use this command `set(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_DEBUG} -Wextra -g -O -Wall -Warray-temporaries -Wconversion -fimplicit-none -fbacktrace -ffree-line-length-0 -fcheck=all -finit-real=nan -ffpe-trap=zero,invalid,overflow,underflow")` to set up compiler flags for debugging but it didn't work.
So what is right way to set up the flags for compiling fortran code?
I used the cmake version 3.17.0, GNU Fortran (Debian 9.3.0-20) 9.3.0 and Debian testing.
The full CMakeLists is

```
project(Simcoflow Fortran)
find_package(MPI REQUIRED)
set(Fortran_COMPILER_FLAGS "-w")
set(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS "${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS} -w")
set(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_DEBUG} -Wextra -g -O -Wall -Warray-temporaries -Wconversion -fimplicit-none -fbacktrace -ffree-line-length-0 -fcheck=all -finit-real=nan -ffpe-trap=zero,invalid,overflow,underflow")
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE DEBUG)
set(HYPRE_INCLUDE_DIR /usr/include/hypre)
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_INCLUDE_DIR)
set(HYPRE_LIBRARIES /usr/lib/libHYPRE.so /usr/lib/libHYPRE_FEI.so /usr/lib/libHYPRE_struct_mv.so /usr/lib/libHYPRE_IJ_mv.so /usr/lib/libHYPRE_parcsr_ls.so)
set(HYPRE_LIBRARIES /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libHYPRE_core.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libHYPRE.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libHYPRE_FEI.so)
include_directories(${MPI_Fortran_INCLUDE_PATH} ${HYPRE_INCLUDE_DIR} ${Simcoflow_INCLUDE_DIR})
link_directories(${MPI_Fortran_LIBRARIES})
#aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST)
list(APPEND SRC_LIST
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/VTKFortran/src/third_party/BeFoR64/src/lib/befor64.F90
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/VTKFortran/src/third_party/BeFoR64/src/lib/befor64_pack_data_m.F90
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/VTKFortran/src/third_party/FoXy/src/lib/foxy.f90
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/VTKFortran/src/third_party/FoXy/src/lib/foxy_xml_file.f90
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/VTKFortran/src/third_party/FoXy/src/lib/foxy_xml_tag.F90
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/VTKFortran/src/third_party/PENF/src/lib/penf_b_size.F90
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/VTKFortran/src/third_party/PENF/src/lib/penf.F90
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/VTKFortran/src/third_party/PENF/src/lib/penf_global_parameters_variables.F90
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/VTKFortran/src/third_party/PENF/src/lib/penf_stringify.F90
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/VTKFortran/src/third_party/StringiFor/src/lib/stringifor.F90
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/VTKFortran/src/third_party/StringiFor/src/lib/stringifor_string_t.F90
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/VTKFortran/src/lib/vtk_fortran_dataarray_encoder.f90
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/VTKFortran/src/lib/vtk_fortran.f90
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/VTKFortran/src/lib/vtk_fortran_parameters.f90
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/VTKFortran/src/lib/vtk_fortran_pvtk_file.f90
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/VTKFortran/src/lib/vtk_fortran_vtk_file.f90
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/VTKFortran/src/lib/vtk_fortran_vtk_file_xml_writer_abstract.f90
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/VTKFortran/src/lib/vtk_fortran_vtk_file_xml_writer_appended.f90
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/VTKFortran/src/lib/vtk_fortran_vtk_file_xml_writer_ascii_local.f90
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/VTKFortran/src/lib/vtk_fortran_vtk_file_xml_writer_binary_local.f90
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/VTKFortran/src/lib/vtk_fortran_vtm_file.F90 
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/Solver.f90
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/Precision.f90
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/MPI.f90
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/Mesh.f90
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/Matrix.f90
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/CutCell.f90 
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/Clsvof.f90
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/PrintResult.f90 
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/PredictUVW.f90
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/ProjectionP.f90 
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/ComputePUVW.f90
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/StateVariables.f90
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/Constants.f90
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/BoundaryInterface.f90
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/BoundaryFunction.f90
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/STL.f90
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/Geometry.f90
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/VTK_mod.f90
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/VTR_mod.f90)

set (LINK_LIBS ${LINK_LIBS} 
    ${MPI_Fortran_LIBRARIES}
    ${HYPRE_LIBRARIES}
    )
list(APPEND SRC_LIST_MAIN
    ${SRC_LIST}
    Main.f90)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST_MAIN})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${LINK_LIBS})
    
add_subdirectory(Test)
```

Comment: "it didn't work" is not a problem description with which we could help you. What exactly is not working? Does compiling crashes? Or compiling succeed, but does it not using your flags? In the latter case, have you checked exact command line executed for compile? (You may inspect this line with `make VERBOSE=1`).

Comment: Hi @Tsyvarev. The compiling worked. However, when I checked with ccmake. These are what I got 
` CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS
 CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_DEBUG        -g
 CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL   -Os -DNDEBUG -Os`
When I try with `make VERBOSE=1` It shown `cd ... -g -O -Wall -Warray-temporaries -Wconversion -fimplicit-none -fbacktrace -ffree-line-length-0 -fcheck=all -finit-real=nan -ffpe-trap=zero,invalid,overflow,underflow ...`.

Comment: So, everything works. CMake cache stores only CACHE variables, but simple form of [set command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html) sets non-cache variable. This is not a problem.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot!